# Occasional `ErrServerError` returned when calling "memcache.Set" against shared Memcache on App Engine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, memcached, google-app-engine-go

I'm occasionally seeing this error after calling `.Set()` following `.Get()` returning something as being not cached, perhaps after being purged.

The description... "memcache: server error" isn't particularly helpful or clear. But, the error seems to be temporary.

**I'm not sure why this is happening,** and whether this indicates that the shared Memcache service is temporarily unavailable altogether... or whether that operation should be perhaps retried at least once after a short delay during the current request?

Does anyone have any insight as to what this error actually means, and how to best work around it?

Comment: `ErrServerError` indicates that a server error occured.Seems like your issue needs internal logs to check the root cause. I recommend [contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: I file a bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/271424757